# Why does sql require a server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL, and i'm trying to understand something basic about it.

Why do we need a server to connect to when using SQL?
In my **very** narrow vision of it, it just uses some databases, which could be implemented as arrays for example (or whatever it is that is implemented "backstage").
For example, if I want to set up a table in my computer and do some operations on it, what usage does the server has? Why can't it "just be there"?

Comment: What do you think it is that interprets the SQL commands and turns them into something that actually executes? What decides what indexes are to be used? What enforces constraints, executes triggers and stored procedures?

Comment: If you write an implementation that takes in SQL, transfers commands over the wire and returns results, you've built a server, regardless of the underlying implementation.  That said, have a look at Linq.

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason for your confusion is too narrow interpretation of the word "server" as a separate hardware box.

A server does not need to run on separate hardware, or even in a separate virtual environment. It could be another process on the same computer, or even a library within your process. What makes it a *server* is an ability to accept and process requests from *clients*. It does not matter where the server runs physically: as long as you follow a protocol in which requests originate on the client side, you have a server.

Comment: Would the same thing be correct if you would have used the word **thread** instead of **process**?
For example, in some Java project lets say I have some field called _"field"_ in some class called _"Data"_, which is a thread (implements Runnable), and i'm trying to change _"field"_ from other threads, would that be considered as server? (assume _"field"_ is public).

Comment: @achie You do not even need a thread - a class that you use like a server can do its job on your main thread. The effect would be the same as calling a server synchronously. As long as your code treats a class like a logical server, it could be thought of as a local server to your program, no matter what its implementation happens to be. Generally, though, servers do imply a certain level of separation - at least to a point that when the server goes down, the application stays up. In-process servers do not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: would an operating system and the computer's memory be considered as a server and database then? Since many processes are trying to access it but the OS itself is the one who decides what to do?

Comment: @achie No, you do not interact with OS in a way that you interact with a server.

Answer (score 4):

What you're envisioning (roughly) is referred to as an in-process database and they do exist for SQL. SQL Server is set up to be used by multiple users or applications so it makes sense for it to be a central server that many clients can connect to so they can share the same data.

If you only want to process data locally, there is SQL Express LocalDB, SQLite and a few others that allow you to essentially embed a SQL engine inside your application.

Answer (score 1):

You are, perhaps, confusing `SQL` the language with `SQL Server`, a Microsoft product that implements SQL.

`SQL` itself has many, many implementations.  Many of those implementations *do not* use a server.  MS Access, SQLite, FileMaker are common SQL-using products that rely on file-sharing rather than a client-server setup to provide multi-user access.  These products can all also be used on a single machine without sharing files.

There are also implementations of SQL that use CSV files for storage although these are less common.

Finally, many of the client-server SQL products offer related, smaller-scale implementations that do not require a server.  These are generally implemented using file-sharing as well.

Comment: So you define a server as something that provides "sharing of data at a more granular level than a file?"

Comment: No, I define a server in what I believe is the standard defintion -- as a process distinct from client.  Generally the server would be a separate workstation but I'm sure we've all run development environments with the client and server on the same workstation (even production systems).  That's still different than in-process libraries or even cases in which the SQL implementation source compiles directly into the executable.

Comment: @Larry Lustig When you say _file-sharing_ do you mean that the "clients" operate on the database and that would be resource consuming, therefore a server is needed? As in noel's answer?

Comment: A shared file system is needed, but not a database server.  The shared file system can be on a separate box (in which case it would be called a file server) or one of the workstations can share its file system (still, technically a file server, but not a database server).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are needing. Some instances of SQL, such as SQLite3, are local and file based. They have no server. Most provide a server because of the problem they address.

But lets address why a server is needed. Consider a Microsoft Access application where the databases are files shared over a network. Suppose 5 people are working with the same file. They each search for something, and the entire file must be passed over the network. Suppose one edits a record. The next time the others do a search, they will have to load the entire file again. If the file is large this is a huge performance hit. This is why servers were created.

A server receives only the SQL. The server does either a search, or an edit, and returns only the data that has been requested. For any database of reasonable size the performance improvement is huge.

Another benefit of a server is access control. With a server you can have multiple accounts and control what databases and even tables they have access to, and what activities they are allowed to perform.

In short, the server was created to address the problems that arise when you have multiple clients working with a single database.